# Asymmetry between definitions of curvature in 2-space and 3-space

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, curves, plane-curves

**Edit**

I am coming back to this question because although the answer I received cleared the matter a little bit I am still confused by the difference between the 2D and 3D case.

So in 2D case one can define abstractly the normal versor N(s) as the unique vector such that the ordered set $\{T(s), N(s)\}$ forms an orthonormal, positively oriented basis of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Then one sees that since $\dot{T}(s)=\frac{d}{ds}T(s)$ is orthogonal to $T(s),$ one may take $N(s)$ to be equal to $\frac{\dot{T}(s)}{\|\dot{T}(s)\|}$ for all $s$ such that $\text{det}(T(s),\dot{T}(s))=1$ and equal to $- \frac{\dot{T}(s)}{\|\dot{T}(s)\|}$ for all $s$ such that the determinant is equal to $-1.$ This determines the sign of the curvature at each point $s.$

In 3D case instead, one starts with $T(s)$ and $N(s)=\frac{\dot{T}(s)}{\|\dot{T}(s)\|},$ which amounts to *choosing by definition* that the curvature must be positive. Then since $B= T \land N$ must be orthogonal to both $T$ and $N,$ those three vectors are linearly independent and thus form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Question**

> Is $B$ the unique vector such that $\{ T, N, B \}$ forms a positively oriented basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

> How can I have an interpretation of the *sign* of the torsion in a way similar to the one I gave above for curvature?

Comment: How do you define the direction of $N(s)$ in the 2D case? More to the point, how would the picture of $k(s) > 0$ look different from the picture of $k(s) < 0$?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins in 2D case $N$ is the unique versor such that $\{T,N\}$ is a positively oriented orthonormal base.

Comment: If you're looking for a 3D phenomenon similar to **signed** curvature in 2D, then you may be interested in mean curvature of surfaces in 3D (or more generally, submanifolds of codimension $1$). Otherwise you face the fundamental problem - a curve in 2D cuts the surrounding space in two pieces, while a curve in 3D doesn't.

Comment: I wonder if people actually read the questions at all before downvoting?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't been explicit in your definitions. In the plane, you can *require* that $T,N$ form a *right-handed* orthonormal basis, and then you find that $dT/ds$ is possibly a negative multiple of $N$ (what is going on here is convexity/concavity). However, in three dimensions, there is no way to define $N$ other than by saying it's the unit vector in the direction of $dT/ds$ (assuming that vector is non-zero, of course). The right-handed orthonormal basis comes in when you add in the binormal vector $B$. It then makes sense to ask if the curve is twisting toward $B$ (positive torsion, by most people's definition) or away from $B$ (negative torsion); here is the sign you were attaching to curvature in the case of a plane curve.

Comment: The definition of $N$ I know of is that it is the unique versor such that $\{T,N\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2.$ But if the curve is $t \mapsto P(t),$ I can reparametrize with arc lenght $s \mapsto P(s)$ and compute   $T(s)$ as $T(s)=(dx(t),dy(t))/\|dP/dt\|,$ and then $N(s)$ is just $N(s)=(-y(t),x(t))/\|dP/dt\|.$ OK so in the 3D case I cannot compute $N$ in this way as in the 2D case, but then what is the definition of $N$ in 3D case?

Comment: If $\{T, N\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, then so is $\{T, -N\}$.

Comment: No, your definition is wrong. There are two choices giving you an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^2$. It's only when you specify the *orientation* that you get a unique vector. At any rate, I suggest you read my differential geometry notes to answer these questions and see examples. (See p. 11 and p. 26 for these particular definitions.)

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I am sorry, in the definition of curvature I said above I forgot to add that $N$ is the unique versor making $\{T,N\}$ a positively oriented orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2,$ which means that $det(T,N)>0.$

Comment: @TedShifrin $N$ is by definition, in the 2D case, the unique versor making $\{T,N\}$ a positively oriented orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2.$ How do I find $N$ in the $3D$ case?

Comment: I've told you in what I wrote. Please go download my notes and read a few pages and learn some examples.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've seen in your notes that the definition is just $dT(s)/\|dT(s)\|.$ This is because $T(s)$ is a versor hence $dT/ds$ is orthogonal to it and then I normalize it. This is clear. What is not clear is why I find a different treatment of the curvature in 3D and 2D. I am already studying the notes of the course I am following with their conventions, I cannot study your notes too because I'm trying to understand the course I am following in the first place

Comment: @TedShifrin Anyway thank you, your answer has cleared my ideas a little bit.

Comment: @ggeolier In that case, it is as Ted Shifrin said. You define $N$ to be the normal vector to your left in the direction of travel. Then positive curvature indicates a turn to the left and negative curvature indicates a turn to the right. In the 3D case, once we know the direction of travel, there are still infinitely many normal directions. Once we pick one direction to be special, say $T'$, then we can pick the other according to a left / right hand rule. The consequence of this is that either the curvature or the torsion will have to be always positive. The usual choice is the curvature.

Comment: The one that is always positive comes from the normal vector that we pick (though $\frac{T'}{\|T'\|}$ seems like a very natural choice, giving us an always positive curvature). The other one can then carry a sign based on our choice of orientation, i.e the sign will tell us if it's "left" or "right" in some sense depending on how we define things.